# How to handle sub_query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I am using codeingniter 3 and i want to get result from my custom query. you can see this query :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `Role`
        LIMIT 10,5) AS T
    ORDER BY
        id DESC
```

Earlier, i used following method :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Role');
$this->db->limit(5, 10);
$first_result = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from("( $first_result ) AS T");
$this->db->order_by('id DESC');
$this->db->get();
```

And i get this error :

```
Error Number: 1327
Undeclared variable: 5 )
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `Role` LIMIT 10, `5 )` AS `T` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Is it possible run this query via Codeigniter?

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: @Viney Yes, I using MySql

Comment: did you solve it? your syntax for query is completely wrong you have to join if there are more than 1 tables